# NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:redshift.psycopg2

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, vagrant, amazon-redshift, vagrantfile

I am trying to connect to redshift from my python code.
my pip installed:

```
psycopg2==2.6.1
redshift-sqlalchemy==0.4.1
SQLAlchemy==1.0.9
```

and my virtual machine has:

```
libpq-dev
python-psycopg2
```

But I am still getting

```
 engine = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://{}:{}@{}'.format(username, password, url))
  File "/opt/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 386, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 51, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "/opt/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 131, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "/opt/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 205, in load
    (self.group, name))
NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:redshift.psycopg2
```

With the same config, I am able to run from my laptop (mac), but on linux, I guess some packages still missing? Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the previous post doesn't really work.

Comment: Instead of struggling with redshift.psycopg2 and directly use postgresql+psycopg2, it works fine :)

Comment: What is the exact solution for this problem ?
I need to connect with redshift and postgresql+psycopg2 does not work.

Answer (score 20):

I found some tutorials that had the driver listed as:
`postgres+psycopg2://` ...and when using that, i received that error:

> NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:redshift.psycopg2

simply changing it to:

```
postgresql+psycopg2://
        ^^
```

fixed it immediately.

Answer (score 14):

I faced same issue and bellow resolution solved it smoothly .

**Environment :**

> Python 3.7

> Conda 4.6.14

**Dependency :**

> sudo apt-get install python-pip

> sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

> pip install --user psycopg2

> pip install --user sqlalchemy

> pip install --user sqlalchemy-redshift

**Connection string :**

```
connection_string = sa_url.URL(
        drivername='postgresql+psycopg2',
        username='admin',
        password='admin',
        host='redshiftone.********.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com',
        port='5439',
        database='redshiftone')
```

[RDS Code Sample,Python](https://github.com/asraful/aws-in-action/tree/main/code-snippets/aws_rds_connectivity_boto3)

Comment: what is sa_url?

Comment: @joydeepbhattacharjee as I recall   from sqlalchemy.engine import url as sa_url

Answer (score 6):

A boneheaded way to get NoSuchModule exception is that the db connection string is in the wrong format.  In my case I got this error when I changed

```
DB_URI = 'postgresql://...'
```

to

```
DB_URI = 'pg8000://...'
```

but should be:

```
DB_URI = 'postgresql+pg8000://
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it when I removed the `__pycache__` directory in `redshift_sqlalchemy` package.

Go to you site-packeges in my case is in my virtualenv.

so `cdvirtualenv` and  `cd lib/python3.5/site-packages/redshift_sqlalchemy` finally `rm __pycache__`.

Comment: Hi, Tried removing the __pycache__ directory, but still gives the same error.

Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:redshift.psycopg2

Comment: did you restart the services? please, give me the steps you are following.

Comment: @ paridin which services to restart ?

For now, I solved it by coming out of virtual environment and running it in the main Python environment. It runs just fine.

Comment: When you start a process and it uses a port it is a service, I use iPython with notebooks to work so I need to restart that service to take a clean process also I suggest removes the `__pycache__` folder from your code, and if you have a requirements file, you should delete your environment and recreate a new one, this is the easy way, if you have time, you must look for references into the site-packages and remove them. I don't recommend use the main environment since you can break it and it will be hard to fix.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
!pip install -U psycopg2-binary sqlalchemy-redshift SQLAlchemy
```

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me. Instead of specifying `redshift+pyscopg2` in the connection URL, you can specify `redshift+redshift_connector`. This will use Amazon's official Redshift Python driver, as well as their SQLAlchemy implementation, instead of `psycopg2`. In this case you wouldn't even need to install `psycopg2` at all if only connecting to Redshift.

You would need to install these 2 modules:

```
pip install sqlalchemy-redshift
pip install redshift_connector
```

And then create the engine like so:

```
engine = create_engine('redshift+redshift_connector://{}:{}@{}'.format(username, password, url))
```

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-the-amazon-redshift-sqlalchemy-dialect-to-interact-with-amazon-redshift/